# How to use IntersectionObserver with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, intersection-observer

I currently have a useEffect with multiple functions within it. I decided to  create an Infinite Scroll feature but I'm having a hard time to make it happen:

This is what I have:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const ref = { current: null };
useEffect(() => {
  getPosts(params).then((result) => {
    setPosts(result);
  }).catch((err) => {});
  ...
  ...
  ...
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      setPage(next);
    }
  }, {
    threshold: 0.1
  }
                                           );
  observer.observe(ref.current);
}, [getPosts, ..., ..., ref])

/// FETCHED POSTS
{posts?.length > 0 ? (
  posts.map((post, index) => (
    <Single
        key={post._id}
        post={post}
        postId={postId}
        setObjects={setPosts}
        objects={posts}
        setTotalResult={setTotalResults}
    />
  ))
) : (
  <NothingFoundAlert />
)}
/// BUTTON
<button ref={ref} style={{ opacity: 0 }}>
    Load more
</button>
```

Not matter what I do, it keeps throwing this error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
```

Has anyone worked with this before?

Comment: try changing `const ref = { current: null };` to `const ref = useRef(null)` and wrap your entire `IntersectionObserver` clause inside `if (ref.current)` condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const ref = { current: null }
// to
const ref = useRef()
```

Should fix the issue, as the error indicates you're trying to observe the assigned `null` instead of an HTMLElement.

When working with IntersectionObserver in React I recommend using a hook created for it like [useInView](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer).